# "Permission denied" when starting binary despite "rwx" priviledge

Tags: permissions, chmod

I am trying to run the statistics software Stata 11 on Ubuntu 11.10. as a regular user and I get the following error message:

```
bash: xstata: Permission denied
```

The user priviledges seem ok to me as a linux newbie, tough:

```
-rwxr-x--x 1 root root 16177752 2009-08-27 16:29 xstata*
```

I would very much appreciate some advice on how to resolve this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to run `xstata` as a regular user (in this case regular means not user root and group membership does not contain root). You do not have right to *read* the file.

Let me quote ([source](http://www.hackinglinuxexposed.com/articles/20030417.html)):

> "Execute" means that this file can be executed as a program. So if
>   the file were a shell script or valid compiled executable (ELF format,
>   etc) named program_name, you could run `./program_name` or, if this
>   directory were in your path, just `program_name`. Without the execute
>   bit, you'd need to type `sh program_name` for a shell script, `perl
>   program_name` for a perl script, etc.

So you either need to be part of the root group or **add read permission to others**. Eg.:

```
sudo chmod o+r xstata
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I followed your advice but now I get the following error message: "bash: .: xstata: cannot execute binary file".
Apparently this means that bash doesn't know how to execute this file. Interestingly, the file can now be executed from Thunar. But how can I do this from bash?

Comment: Could you run `file xstata` and post the output? This command identifies the file type. Eg.: http://pastie.org/2808999

Comment: This command outputs the following:
`xstata: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.4.0, stripped`
Any idea how to run this?

Comment: Now please run `uname -a` to identify your system architecture, and post the output.

Comment: Happy to do so: `Linux dr 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:56:25 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Well, both the executable and the OS seems to be 64 bit, so it should not be the problem. Considering Thunar can start the program it should run from bash. Do you start it with `./xstata` or `bash ./xstata`, because the latter should not work.

Comment: Yes indeed, I tried starting it with the latter, but the first one works perfectly. Thanks a million!

Comment: I'm glad that I could help!